# I want to display a product in RecycleView with volley

Tags: android, arrays, json

I tried a lot of online codes. This is my JSON object. please help me to display this in `RecycleView` with the use of `GridLayout`. Please find below JSON object.

```
{
    "total": 3,
    "per_page": 10,
    "current_page": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "next_page_url": null,
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "from": 1,
    "to": 3,
    "data": [
        {
            "product_id": 31,
            "image": "http://celebauc.com/app/uploads/funkymobile.jpg",
            "location": "mumbai",
            "price": "400.0000",
            "status": 1,
            "name": "Itarsia",
            "description": "mouse",
            "discount": {}
        },
        {
            "product_id": 13,
            "image": "http://celebauc.com/app/uploads/funkymobile.jpg",
            "location": "Mumbai",
            "price": "100.0000",
            "status": 1,
            "name": "Dynamic Website",
            "description": "d s das asf sdfsdf sdf sdfs fsdfsd f fsd fsdf dsfsdf",
            "discount": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what did you tried so far so your efforts first

Comment: **Welcome to Stack Overflow**, StackOverflow is neither a forum, tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can [**help with certain problems**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's your job to [**put some efforts**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) in the first place, including elementary [**(re)search**](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=KlC2WdDPCKzT8gfFz72QDw). Read [**how to ask perfect question**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON objects within JSON array with android volley library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40198435/parse-json-objects-within-json-array-with-android-volley-library)

Comment: do you know about json parsing?

Comment: I know to parsing a json . it shows me lot of error thats why I am asking here .

Comment: @anujmourya share your error

Comment: @NileshRathod  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONArray org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: @anujmourya check my below ans https://stackoverflow.com/a/46462665/7666442

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
            String total = obj.getString("total");
            String per_page = obj.getString("per_page");
            // now as per above get all your data like current_page,last_page,

            JSONArray data = obj.getJSONArray("data");
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = data.getJSONObject(i);
                String product_id = jsonObject.getString("product_id");// get id from product_id json object
                String image = jsonObject.getString("image");// get id from product_id json object
                String location = jsonObject.getString("location");// get id from product_id json object
                // as per above get all yourJSONArray data 
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
            yourEndpointUrl, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray dataArray= object.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = data.getJSONObject(i);
            String product_id = jsonObject.optString("product_id");
            String image = jsonObject.optString("image");
                }
            }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                }
            });
```